# Batch file negative numbers unable to be detected by "IF" command

Tags: batch-file

I've been working on a RPG style game on my desktop running windows 7
I've been using batch to make this game. I've been having issues with negative numbers...
If your/enemy's health enters negative numbers, you become invincible. The LSS,LEQ,GTR,GEQ does not seem to work.
This is how I determine if you are dead or the monster is;

```
If "%phealth%" LSS "0" goto :dead.                          
If "mhealth%" LSS "0" goto :Mdead
```

If I use GTR or GEQ the first attack will kill the monster no matter what if I use LSS or leq it didn't work how I intended it.
Everything is randomly generated via;

```
Set /a "mhealth=%random% %%mlvl%-1+9
```

Player health and level is not random but can be changed
Are there any solutions or errors that I have overlooked. Most pages didn't help either. I need it so if health enters negative you/the monster die

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code properly. And those do not add quotes to `"%phealth%"` and `"0"`.

Comment: If you happened to read the help for the `IF` command you might have seen this. **You can also use numerical comparisons above:
`IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 goto okay`**. Do you see any quotes around that?

Comment: You look like you're supposed to be doing a remainder calculation. As you are using a batch file you need to double the percent character, `Set/A mhealth= %random% %% %mlvl% - 1 + 9` _(there is no need to include the percent characters on the %mlvl% variable)_. I have included spaces to help you see the separation between conponents, leaving those will do no harm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enclose the operands in quotes, the comparison is performed *alphabetically*. The reason for quotes is (often) to protect against an operand being empty - but that can also be accomplished by using `if [not] defined ...` . For a *numeric* comparison, remove the quotes.